# Must be and must have been

Tags: grammar

Is any of these sentences correct?

There *must be* something happened in the past that traumatized him.

There *must have been* something happened in the past that traumatized him.

*And*;

Do I need to add 'that' after 'something'?

*Like*, There (must be or must have been) something *that* happened in the past that traumatized him.

Answer (score 1):

> There must have been something that happened in the past that traumatized him.

To me the first sentence has mixed tenses: "be" conflicts with "in the past".

Comment: How about adding that after something? Or is there other way to say it?